# how to change value on click event and change value again on click event on the same bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a chatbox for my friends to use and before a friend can join the room I want them to click on a bottom which has a default value of JoinChat. AND when they click that I want to send request to the database using ajax to allow them enter the room and then change the value of the bottom to LeaveChat

Assuming they have entered the room and they wan to leave the room so when they click on the same bottom, send another request to database to disconnect them from the chat room.

```
<input type="button" value="JoinChat" onClick="" id="btn">
```

Comment: do a ajax call on success function change buton text value , I think you may have a better luck on freelance.com if you want for someone to code it for you

Comment: i agree with @madalinivascu, its not as simple as that, you will need a function to trigger the action. It can be done with ajax, You may check google.

Comment: Use google and find an already done solution, problem solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is quick solution:

```js
var isConnected = false;
var NOTCONNECTEDTEXT = 'JoinChat'
var CONNECTEDTEXT = 'LeaveChat'

function btnClick(event){
  isConnected = !isConnected
  
  document.querySelector('#btn').value = 
    isConnected ? CONNECTEDTEXT : NOTCONNECTEDTEXT
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="JoinChat" onClick="btnClick()" id="btn">
```

Just implement what you need, but the code is bad, to improve the code, recommend you use library like React.